# Comparing DateTime variable to DateTime data type column with Null values in it

Tags: c#, datetime, null

I have to do a c# search on records in an array from a sql server db
 using 3 data elements. One of the data elements has to be a DateTime element in a column called DateOfBirth. Unfortunately there are a lot of null values in this column and I can't figure out how to compare a DateTime variable to a field with `NULL` values. I see a lot of answers that appear to be close to what I need here, but nothing has helped. Thanks for any help, This has been my format.

```
if ((DateTime)dt == (DateTime)temp[i].Individual.DateOfBirth)
    GlobalNum3.bnum3 = 1;
```

Comment: So what happens with this code?  Do you get a `NullReferenceException`?  What are the compile time types of `dt` and `DateOfBirth`?

Comment: would it be an option to alter the SQL query so that entries with NULL datetimes are excluded? You could then process those entries in a seperate method. Something like `...WHERE DateOfBirth IS NOT NULL [...]` would do the job.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that `dt` is already a `DateTime`, in which case it can't be null (`DateTime` is a `struct`) and there's no need to cast it.In addition, either `temp[i].Individual.DateOfBirth` is a `DateTime` too and so cannot be `null` either, or it's a `Nullable<DateTime>`.

Assuming both are `DateTimes`, DB `nulls` will be set to `DateTime.MinValue`, so just compare the values:

```
if (dt == (DateTime)temp[i].Individual.DateOfBirth)
{
    GlobalNum3.bnum3 = 1;
}
```

However, if `temp[i].Individual.DateOfBirth` is a `Nullable<DateTime>`, it might be `null`, or might simply have no value, so use it like this:

```
var possibleDateOfBirth = temp[i].Individual.DateOfBirth;
if (possibleDateOfBirth != null &&
    possibleDateOfBirth.HasValue &&
    dt == possibleDateOfBirth.Value)
{
    GlobalNum3.bnum3 = 1;
}
```

Comment: A DateTime in .NET can't be null. It's DateTime.MinValue. (DateTime is a struct type).

Comment: @SteffenWinkler, yep, that's what I said "I'm assuming that `dt` is already a `DateTime`, in which case it can't be null"

Comment: in that case I don't get your if statement :/

Comment: @SteffenWinkler, hmm, I see what you mean. I only half thought through the `DateTimes`. `temp[i].Individual.DateOfBirth` either is a `DateTime` and so can't be null or must be a Nullable<DateTime>. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are querying the DB then try testing the nullable .`HasValue` property like this:

```
if (temp[i].Individual.DateOfBirth.HasValue && dt == temp[i].Individual.DateOfBirth.Value)
{
   GlobalNum3.bnum3 = 1;
}
```

Obviously I'm assuming you are testing `DateTime?` properties.